# set a trigger dependent on multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Is there a way to set trigger dependent on multiple linked tables? (linked by relationship such as PK/FK relationship). The use case is given below:

I've got 5 tables like this:

```
TableA{
  idA SERIAL, PRIMARY KEY
}

TableB{
  idB  integer references tableA(idA);
}

TableC{
  idC  integer references tableA(idB);
}

TableD{
  idD  integer references tableA(idB);
}

TableE{
  idE  integer references tableA(idB);
}
```

The information linked in the 5 tables comprise to give a full meaning of an `entity`.

The problem is I've got to call a procedure manually when I've completed an update for a
particular entity for a nodejs api:

```
payloadForEntire5Tables = { // define payload}
await nodejsService.updateAllTables(payloadForEntire5Tables);
makeRawQuery('CALL procedure_all_data_update_completed()');
```

so I'd like to set a TRIGGER that would call the proc after all data for a particular `entity` has been written i.e. the data has been written to all 5 tables successfully

I wonder if such a facility is provided by `postgres`? Is there
any way I can achieve this?

Comment: ?? Trigger is a procedure which as executed as a reaction on some data changing action. If you want all 5 tables to be edited (the data is inserted into them) consistently than you'd simply use complex INSERT query which performs consistent inserts into all tables.

Comment: Yea this doesn't make a ton of sense. Can you clarify what you mean by "*after all data for a particular entity has been written*"?...are you saying after **all** 5 tables have been written to or after **any** of the 5 tables have been written to?

Comment: @J.D. I mean after the data has been written to all 5 tables

Comment: What's the last table you write to of the 5?...could you just add the trigger to that table itself?

Comment: It could be any one, we may maintain the order, but, I'd like to avoid that